# will Method chaining create intermediate variable in stack?

Tags: javascript, java, jvm, heap-memory, stack-memory

> Method Chaining: as the concept stated, Each method returns an object, allowing the
>   calls to be chained together in a single statement. Chaining is
>   syntactic sugar which eliminates the need for intermediate variables,

just want to know that, does Method chaining(`return a reference to a object`) creating `(anonymous? )intermediate variables` in `stack`?

**In Java**

**eg**: `a.functionA().functionB().functionC().functionD()`

in the statement above,

A. after `a` called `functionA`, will the `JVM` allocate a `temporary variable`(point to the object B) in the `stack` in order to call the next function(like `function B`)?

B.Or just `variable a(in stack)` called function `functionA`, then `returned value(address)(stored somewhere else)` point to `object B` in **`heap`**, **no intermediate variables** created in `stack`?

**In JavaScript**

eg: 
Person has a `prototype` object, then you can use the `prototype` to access the property inside, for example, the`sayHi()function` in that case, `Person.prototype.sayHi`, will this create a intermediate variable in stack ?

Comment: @KaustubhKhare, I don't think that question answers the technical details asked about in this question.

Comment: @KaustubhKhare, could you please just answer me mate. this is not duplicate

Comment: @31piy what about prototype in javascript, Person has a prototype object, then you can use the prototype to access the property inside, in that case, `Person.prototype.anything`, will this create a intermediate variable in stack

Comment: @Ruizhi -- The question didn't term anything related to JavaScript (apart from the tags). It references JVM, at all the places. If you want specific anwers, then please edit your question to limit its scope.

Comment: @31piy I have updated the javascript prototype version

Comment: @31piy, hi mate, can you please tell me your understanding? do you think it will create a temporary variable in stack in javascript ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the implementation.

But, in most implementations, the chaining just update the current instance and return its reference so no intermediate variables are created.

Ex:

```
public class A {
  private int a;
  private int b;

  public A(){}

  public A functionA() {
     return this; // In most implementations, the `this` is returned for chaining
  }

  public A functionB() {
     return this;
  }
}
```

Comment: where is the returned reference stored? in the heap or in the register of cpu

Comment: That's just normal Java object reference. Typically, the object instance is on the heap and the reference is on the stack

Comment: i mean, in the case i stated above, when `a` called `functionA`, `functionA` returned a `reference to object B`, that's why it can call `functionB` in `Object B`, i want to know if there is actual `intermediate variable` **created** during this process in **stack**?

Comment: It depends on your implementation, if you create new then new reference is returned. You control the flow, nothing is hidden in this case

Comment: but, i'm not creating a new variable to receive the returned address, just simply a method chaining, `a.functionA().functionB().functionC().functionD()`, and the last function returned a void

Comment: hi mate, could you please tell me your understanding about this, do you think it will or will not create a temporary variable in stack when it comes to method chaining